# What to do when a user asks a question and keeps updating with new questions?

Tags: discussion

Yesterday I put a lot of time helping someone very new to SO and programming in general. It even needed a chat session. Near the end he didn't get how to implement the code I posted and basically asked : "write it for me"

The bugs he created by doing a bad copy/paste job had nothing to do with the original question and would have taken it completely off topic. The question itself at the moment is a frankenstein beast composed off the original question in text and a mangled version of the code from my answer.

I suggested an edit to the question, rolling it back to before he posted the code in. This got rejected because it did no longer reflect the question of the OP. At the moment the answers do not cover all the problems (which would involve teaching him all the basics).

So is it better to leave a bad question out there that is not at all helpful to other people or again suggest a roll back, and maybe get it back to a state where it is a simple question with a correct answer.

[the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32356321/making-a-text-view-respond-to-text-typed-by-the-user/32356644#32356644)

Comment: yup that's it! Luckily I got out, explained how to use google and youtube tutorials in chat. Except now I am left with a nice answer on a horrible question and it doesn't have to be that way. It can be a nice answer on a bland duplicate question.

Comment: What you do is: Falcon.... PUUUNCH!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What I do in this instance is to roll back the edit (ask a moderator to do so if needed), and leave a comment to the effect of "Changing your question after you've received answers is inappropriate, as it invalidates the answers you've received. It can even make those answers wrong, and adversely affect the reputation of those who answered. If you now have a new or additional question, create a new post and ask it there; you can link back to this one if needed for reference."

If the poster has an issue with that, or insists on the changes, flag the post with a custom flag. Make a clear comment to the moderator with the reason for the flag, such as "Edit war for chameleon question. Poster insists on changing after receiving answers."; I've always (at least so far) found the moderators receptive.

Comment: I like your comment suggestion ;)

Comment: I just used this suggestion today - was exactly what I was looking for… https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51838169/filling-the-width-of-imageview-without-stretching-the-image